# $x=x_p+x_n$ is given, asked to find the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is :

Find a 2 by 3 system $Ax=b$ whose complete solution is :

$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}+w
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
3\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So I treated this as $x=x_p+x_n$
where the 2nd matrix is $x_n$

So I said to myself find a matrix such that it's nullspace is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
3\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$ I found one but how can it relate it to the particular solution. I know that particular solution would be in the row space of A. But I couldn't manage to find a matrix which contains $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ in it's rowspace and $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
3\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$ in it's nullspace at the same time. What to do here, Help me out please.

Comment: I dont think that the solution is unique. Are you required to find one possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pick just the matrix, but also the right hand side! So, if you've found a matrix $A$ with the given null space, just let $b=Ax_p$. With this choice

$$
b=Ax_p = Ax_p + Ax_n=Ax.
$$

Edit: by the way, you cannot find a matrix whose null space contains $[1\ 3\ 0]$ and its row space contains $[1\ 2\ 0]$, since row space and null psace are orthogonal, and those two vectors are not orthogonal.

Comment: This is more of a comment.

Comment: Why? Doesn't it answer the question of finding a system with the given solution expression?

Comment: doesn't answer my question, would have been better with an example (example could be taken as my question) so. Would appreciate if you edit your answer

Comment: Hum, yes, it does. The question asks to find a 2x3 system with the given general solution. You said you found a matrix with the right null space (great!), and I explained how to find the missing part (the right hand side). Then, in the edit, I also explained why $[1\ 2\ 0]$ cannot be in the row space. How is this not an answer to your question?

Comment: Doesn't A transform particular solutions(from the row space) to the column space? So if 1 2 0 isn't in the rowspace since collapse has 1 3 0 how will I find the matrix A?

Comment: You said you found a matrix whose null space is $[1\ 3\ 0]$, right? Now you need to find a right hand side which will give you the desired particular solution. That's all you need. And notice that A does not transform 'solutions from the row space' to vectors in the column space. It transforms *any* vector $x$ in the *domain* of $A$ into a vector in the column space of $A$. But such $x$ need not to be in the row space of $A$, that is, it's not necessary that $A^ty=x$ has a solution... Moreover, a solution needs not to be in the row space of A.